# Why is the verb not in 2nd position in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure

> More time to prepare
> Mehr Zeit zur Vorbereitung

Interested in why the verb is in last position in this sentence just for my understanding :)

Comment: Quick answer, it's not a complete sentence and there is no verb. *Vorbereitung* = "preparation" is a noun here. Perhaps if you gave more context someone could provide a more complete explanation.

Comment: Note: the V2-rule only applies to *finite* (conjugated) verbs in *main* clauses. Not to infinitives, not to participles, not to gerunds and not to subclauses or questions.

Comment: Any dictionary or conjugation table will tell you that *prepare* is a verb and *Vorbereitung* is a noun.

Answer (score 5):

Because there is no verb in your (non-)sentence.

As already answered (in the comments)---and can be deduced from the rule that capitalization suggests (but need not be) nominalization---*Vorbereitung* is a noun.

Answer (score 2):

### Uppercase first letter = noun!

It is very easy to identify any noun in written German, because all nouns, and only nouns are written with an uppercase first letter. An uncertainty exists only for the first word of a sentence, because the first word of a sentence is always written with an uppercase first letter, no matter which part of speech it belongs to.

Your word in question is not the first word in the sentence. This means: If it's written with an uppercase first letter, it **must** be a noun. It can't be any other part of speech, and this means, for a word that starts with an uppercase letter, that's not the first word in a sentence, it's impossible to be a verb.

**[die Vorbereitung](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Vorbereitung)**

- This word has a grammatical gender (which means you can use it together with an article), like every German noun.
- It can be declined into all four grammatical cases like every German noun.
- It can be the core of a nominal group which for example can be the subject of a sentence.

Verbs do not have any of the properties listed above.

But many parts of speech have subclasses, and within the class of nouns there is the subclass of nominalized words. But be careful: They have misleading names for historic reasons and because of the way how they are created:

- Substantivierte Verben
  (in English: nominalized verbs)
  Examples: Das Laufen, die Lauferei, das Heulen, das Geheul, das Schreiben, der Schreiber, das Berühren, die Berührung, ...
- Substantivierte Adjektive
  (in English: nominalized adjectives)
  Examples: Das Reine, die Reinheit, der Einsame, die Einsamkeit, ...
- Substantivierte Partizipien
  (in English: nominalized participles)
  Examples: Das Geschriebene, der Schreibende, das Gesprochene, der Sprechende, ...
- Substantivierte Zahlwörter
  (in English: nominalized numerals)
  Examples: Die Eins, der Einser, die Zwei, der Zweier, ...

All these words are nouns. Non of them is a verb, an adjective etc. Although for example the name *"nominalized verb"* implies that such a word is a verb, it's still a noun, because all these words have a grammatical Gender, which means, they can be used with an article, they can be the subject of a sentence and so on.

---

### Your "sentence" is just a nominal group

What you believe to be a sentence is just a nominal group. It is one part of a sentence, and this part can be the subject or an object of a sentence.

- subject

  > **Mehr Zeit zur Vorbereitung** führt zu besseren Ergebnissen.
  > <sup>**More time for preparation** leads to better results.</sup>
- accusative object

  > Das Team benötigt **mehr Zeit zur Vorbereitung.**
  > <sup>The team needs **more time for preparation.**</sup>

You will find the verbs of both sentences (*»führt«* and *»benötigt«*) at position 2 of each sentence.

**Zeit**
The core of this nominal group is the noun *»Zeit«,* and it has a determiner on its left side (*»mehr«*) and an attribute on its right (*»zur Vorbereitung«*).

**mehr**
The [determiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner) on the left side is a quantifier, which is realized by an indefinite pronoun.

**zur Vorbereitung** = zu der Vorbereitung
Note, that *»zur«* is a contraction of *»zu«* + *»der«,* and to analyze this part of a sentence, it's better to replace the contraction by its components.
The attribute right of the core is a prepositional phrase that consists of a preposition (*»zu«*) and another nominal group (*»der Vorbereitung«*). This nominal group is in dative case, because the preposition *zu* needs to have it in this case. And it consists of two words (*»der«* + *»Vorbereitung«*), where the first (*»der«*) is a definite article (feminine singular in dative case) and the second (*»Vorbereitung«*) is a **noun.**

The word *»Vorbereitung«* must be a noun for several reasons:

- It is written with an uppercase first letter
- It appears with an article (*»der«* which is hidden inside the contraction *»zur«*)
- It is the core of a nominal group (*»der Vorbereitung«*)

---

### more time to prepare ≠ mehr Zeit zur Vorbereitung

These are the literal translations:

> more time **to prepare** = mehr Zeit **um *(etwas)* vorzubereiten**
> mehr Zeit **zur Vorbereitung** = more time **for preparation**

The part *»um (etwas) vorzubereiten«* is named in German *»erweiterter Infinitiv mit zu«.* But it needs something to fill the place where here *»(etwas)«* is written, so you can't use this direct translation without changing the meaning of the sentence. You have to use a different construction than in English to create a phrase with the same meaning.

For *»erweiterter Infinitiv mit zu«* please consult other questions here on German.stackexchange, because this is definitely out of scope of your original question.